# Kerberos is weak: i need to encrypt user identity

Tags: kerberos

I do not like the fact that Kerberos for all types of packets like AS-REQ, AS-REP, TGS-REQ, TGS-REP etc is sending identity (like username) in a plain text.

Is it possible to reconfigure AD and Kerberos so that identity is send encrypted for example in anonymous TLS tunnel ? (other decent protocols like EAP-PEAP or TLS1.3 can send identity is a secure way).

I was pretty sure it's possible but i can not find any solution now....

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in three ways:

1. **"Kerberos over HTTPS"** using the MS-KKDCP extension. This uses a regular TLS tunnel to protect the requests.

   On the DC side, the [RD Gateway role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/key-distribution-center-proxy) automatically provides a KKDCP proxy (as the feature seems to be mostly RDP-oriented), but the proxy can also be [set up manually](https://syfuhs.net/kdc-proxy-for-remote-access) without any required roles (instructions therein provided by a MS developer). Alternatively, [kdcproxy](https://github.com/latchset/kdcproxy) is a simple Python WSGI app that can act as the proxy.

   On the Windows client side, the proxy can be specified either [within .rdp files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/key-distribution-center-proxy), or [globally via GPO](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Kerberos::KdcProxyServer). Meanwhile, Linux (MIT/Heimdal) clients can directly specify the proxy URL for `kdc=` in their krb5.conf files, or they can retrieve it from DNS `URI` records.
2. **"Kerberos armoring"** using the FAST extension. This uses another set of Kerberos credentials (e.g. machine keytab) to encrypt the AS-REQ.

   Active Directory appears to have native support for FAST as part of "compound authentication" together with the machine credentials. You can [enable it via GPO](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.KDC::CbacAndArmor); the armored requests will reveal the machine identity but not the user identity.

   For MIT/Heimdal Kerberos, acquire a generic initial ticket using either standard "anonymous PKINIT" (which is roughly the Kerberos equivalent of EAP-TLS) or the Heimdal-specific GSS-SAnon, then use it with FAST to protect the real AS-REQ. Anonymous PKINIT only reveals a generic "@REALM" identity.
3. Use a **VPN** for Kerberos.

   When accessing the AD domain from outside, you'll generally want a VPN for all other AD DC communications *anyway* (e.g. you really do not want to expose CLDAP or RPC services to the public Internet), so you might as well use it for Kerberos too.